# TeamCity how to set JVM Arguments

Tags: jvm, teamcity, jvm-arguments

my teamcity build server has following JVM Arguments:

-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=270m

sometimes it shows some memory problem message like "TeamCity server memory usage for PS Old Gen pool exceeded 91% of 341 MB maximum available. 437 MB used of 506 MB total heap available. See the TeamCity documentation for possible solutions."

i read here https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-SettingUpMemorysettingsforTeamCityServer that the minimum recommended settings are: -Xmx750m -XX:MaxPermSize=270m.

how/where do i change this setting?

Answer (score 5):

Internal properties are read after the JVM is started and so the heap settings will not take effect if put where [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238783) suggests. I was looking into how to do this for a TeamCity container and the best option seems to be to use environment variables (`TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS`).  For a container, those can be set by passing `-e TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS='...'` when creating the container.

Answer (score 4):

In TC9+ it is possible to set this variable in TC Server GUI:
Administration -> Diagnostics -> Internal Properties -> Edit internal properties

For 64-bit JVM the recommended setting is:

```
TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=270m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=350m
```

Just add this line to the Internal properties edit box

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend adding the JVM memory options in the startup  script (start.sh) for server based startup using the variable `TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS` . Please do not set it in the profile of the userid that runs teamcity.

This [link](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-SettingUpMemorysettingsforTeamCityServer) should be helpful to you.

In case you want different memory settings for server and agent(usually that's the case), please be selective in naming the variables so that there is a difference in identifying the JVM options for server and agent startup.

As a rule of thumb for teamcity setups, I normally let my teamcity server have 20% more memory than my avg usage to account for any increased load during peak usage periods.